# Removing records from related tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables:

- **reports**
- **report_contents**

which are related by foreign key **content_id** on **reports** table.

I need to create procedure which delete some reports together with their contents, like this:

```
DELETE FROM report_contents WHERE id IN 
     (SELECT content_id FROM reports WHERE extra_value = extraValue)

DELETE FROM reports WHERE extra_value = extraValue
```

But it is impossible to delete records from **report_contents** table firstly, because there is constrain on **content_id** column on **reports** table.

On the other hand when I delete records from **reports** table firstly, I won't know what report_contents should be deleted then...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delete_reports (extraValue NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
/* removing reports with extra_value = extraValue */
/* removing their report_contents */
END;
```

What is the best way to do this? (I don't want to add *on delete cascade* constrain)

Comment: which is the parent and child table?

Comment: @BhupeshC, REPORT_CONTENTS is a parent table. REPORTS table has 'content_id' column (foreign key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of ids is relatively small (i.e. just a few hundred or thousand) you can comfortably store the IDs to delete temporarily in a PL/SQL array.

```
PROCEDURE delete_reports (extraValue NUMBER) IS
  TYPE id_table IS TABLE OF reports.content_id%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  ids id_table;

BEGIN

  /* which reports to delete? */
  SELECT content_id BULK COLLECT INTO ids
  FROM reports WHERE extra_value = p_extra_value;

  /* removing reports with extra_value = extraValue */
  DELETE reports WHERE extra_value = p_extra_value;

  /* removing their report_contents */
  FORALL i IN 1..ids.COUNT
    DELETE report_contents WHERE id = ids(i);

END delete_reports;
```

If the number of ids is large (e.g. millions or more) then I'd probably break this into a loop and get the ids in batches.

Answer (score 0):

Since its an `SP`, you could use an intermediate `TABLE` variable to store your results

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delete_reports (extraValue NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TABLE table
    ( CONTENT_ID int)

    INSERT INTo @TABLE
    SELECT content_id FROM reports WHERE extra_value = extraValue

    DELETE FROM reports B WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TABLE A WHERE A.Content_id=B.Content_id)

    DELETE FROM report_contents C WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TABLE A WHERE A.Content_id=C.ID)
END
```

I am assuming that you could use `CONTENT_ID` to `delete` from both tabes

Comment: But I need to create procedure delete_reports(extraValue NUMBER). Is it possible to declare table variable inside of procedure?

Comment: @DavidSilva Actually you can - **especially because its an `SP`**. You can declare variables in an SP or a function but not in a view. You can find a lot of online material on the subject.

Comment: Thanks! Could you expand abbreviation 'SP' ?

Comment: SP - Stored Procedure

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**  Thanks to a helpful commenter, who pointed out how my original solution left out a relationship between`CONTENT_ID` of the `REPORTS` table and `ID` of `REPORT_CONTENT` table.  The cursor query of my first attempt assumed that any orphaned ID in the `REPORT_CONTENT` table would be an ideal candidate for deletion.  This assumption is not supportable so I rewrote the cursor into two different cursors below.

---

I think the original post was a question about how to do this in *ORACLE*`? Here's an alternate approach using an Oracle PL/SQL CURSOR.

```
 CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_delete_reports ( p_extra_value in varchar2 )
    is

    CURSOR del_reports is
       SELECT content_id FROM reports WHERE extra_value = p_extra_value
          FOR UPDATE;

    CURSOR del_contents (p_content_id IN number) is
       SELECT id
         FROM report_contents
        WHERE id = p_content_id 
          FOR UPDATE;

 BEGIN
    FOR i in del_reports
      LOOP

      DELETE FROM reports
       WHERE current of del_reports;

      FOR j in del_contents(p_content_id => i.content_id)
        LOOP

        DELETE from report_contents
        WHERE current of del_contents;
      END LOOP;

    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;

 END proc_delete_reports;
```

Given the appropriate syntax, you can modify the contents of a cursor output as you walk through each value in a loop.

Comment: This assumes that each `report_contents` will always have at least one row in `reports`. What if, before calling this procedure, there was a row in `report_contents` that had no rows in `reports`? This procedure would delete that record as well, even though it doesn't match the parameter `p_extra_value`.